# is $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] safe?

Tags: php, security

I'm using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to generate a dynamic back link.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">Return to..blah</a>
```

Is it reasonably safe to do so?

Comment: Safe as in protected against XSS attacks, or safe as in "will always contain a valid value"?

Comment: REFERER isn't always present so your method won't work in some cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not like that.

It might not be present. (It might be wrong, some personal firewall packages obfuscate the referer for privacy reasons, violating the HTTP spec along the way)

You should run anything coming from outside your system through `htmlspecialchars` to guard against XSS attacks (although, IIRC, the referer should never have any dangerous characters in it as they should be URL safe you should keep in the habit of always being cautious).

Browsers come with back buttons though, there is no need to try to duplicate their functionality (especially when, with this, if the user clicks a link marked "back" it doesn't take them back in their history, so clicking the normal back button will conceptually take them forwards).

Comment: It might not be set at all, not only blank.

Answer (score 6):

It may be safe, but it is **not reliable**: due to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3), `HTTP_REFERER` is optional (some clients don't send this header at all, and some "security" software strips this out from any HTTP request), and there are numerous ways to modify this header. Some browsers send the referring page, some send a blank string, some don't send this at all, some may send bogus data, some may send Aunt Matilda; and moreover, you can't tell whether you're getting valid data in this header or not.

So, no, I would never trust that `HTTP_REFERER` contains the previous page, and neither should you.

Comment: +1 I have had the first file referenced in the last HTML requested page set as the referer several times, usually `favicon.ico` or a css file. This happened in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

It's not.
It might not be set, unwanted or even unsafe.

Concider the following:

1. User types in your url and hits go. There will not be an referrer. Not only will your back-button not work, you'll receive an notice error as well.
2. The visitor comes from an external source (lets say google) on your product page. do you want to send your visitor back to google? I don't think so.
3. The header can be modified, I'd go for either double checking it, or not using it at all.