# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] does not work alltime

Tags: php, http-referer

I am filtering a page with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Let "pageb.php" filter whether a user have come from "pagea.php" (although it is not reliable) by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

It works well until "pagea.php" has a preceding query string like "pagea.php?q=10". Then if a user goes from "pagea.php?q=10" to "pageb.php" it is not detected by "pageb.php":

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']='http://pagea.php'){
 echo 'This user has come from page a';
}else{
 echo 'This user has come from another page';
}
```

How can I detect a user came from "pagea.php" even with preceding query `string q=10`?

Comment: If both files are on your server, why don't you keep a `$_SESSION` variable with "last visited page"?

Comment: Here's a discussion on the matter. tl;dr: you cannot rely on HTTP_REFERER: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934747/is-serverhttp-referer-safe - do you want to check where your users are coming from within your own domain or from other domains? if stricly the former you could use sessions to track pages for instance.

Comment: In your pseudo-URL-code, something like `if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'http://pagea.php') === 0)` perhaps?

Comment: You do realize that that is sent by the client and it won't necessarily get sent and won't necessarily be telling the truth when it does, right?

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is unreliable and can be manipulated, so if your script deals with sensitive information, this is not the way to go. Also use `strpos` for searching words/characters inside a string.

Comment: Look mom! I am coming from [http://superduperawesomereferer.com](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/bBg2b)! TL;DC (too long didn't click). The referer header is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) to check if a string contains another string:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'pagea.php') !== false) {
  echo 'from page a';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use comparision operator not assignment
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']='http://pagea.php'){

= will be ==